# AJAX/JS/PHP- Echoing values without a page refresh or button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently working with a JS/AJAX functions that works without a page refresh or button click. I have run into some issue when echoing the value. For example if I change this line `$email   = $_POST['name'];` it works perfect but if i use the actual value of email like `$email = $_POST['email'];` it doesn't work. I am new learner with both JS & php.

Can someone tell me why is giving such results? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var timer = null; 
        var dataString;   
        function submitForm(){
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "test1.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#special').html($('#resultval', result).html());
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        $('#email').on('keyup', function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 0050);
            var name = $("#email").val();
            dataString = 'name='+ name;
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?

if($_POST) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (preg_match('|^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$|i', $email)) {
        echo ('<div id="special"><span id="resultval">'.$email.'</span></div>');
    }
    else {
        echo ('<div id="special"><span id="resultval">Include a valid email address.</span></div>');

    }           
}
?>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you are making a mistake with dataString. Change it to dataString = 'email=' + name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you explicitly specify a parameter 'name' to hold the email address. There is no parameter 'email' you speficy. Loot at this line in your JS code:

```
dataString = 'name='+ name;
```

So there is no sense trying to read the email address in php like you do:

```
$email            = $_POST['email'];
```

You have to change the JS code to name the parameter the same as you are trying to read it inside the php code.

---

So most likely all you have to do is change you current JS code from

```
        var name = $("#email").val();
        dataString = 'name='+ name;
```

to

```
        var email = $("#email").val();
        dataString = 'email='+ email;
```

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On the client side browser makes a request with parameter `name` (because `dataString = 'name=' + name;`), so on the server side you can get the value by `$POST['name']`.